# Shoulda::Matchers::Independent::DelegateMethodMatcher: undefined method `allow_nil'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, shoulda-matchers

I'm trying to test a delegate method of my `Comment` model using *shoulda-matchers (3.1.2)* & *rspec-rails (3.7.2)* in my *rails (5.0.1)* application with *ruby 2.5.0-p0 (x86_64-linux)*
and getting this error:

```
1) Comment delegation 
     Failure/Error: it { should delegate_method(:name).to(:user).allow_nil }

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `allow_nil' for #<Shoulda::Matchers::Independent::DelegateMethodMatcher:0x00005587de5bc488>
     # ./spec/models/comment_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00225 seconds (files took 3.62 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure
```

The code is quite clean and straightforward, I think there could be some errors with the library rather than my implementation code. Does anyone know what is going wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: What's your shoulda-matchers gem version?

Comment: @SebastianPalma shoulda-matchers (3.1.2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must upgrade your shoulda-matchers gem to the version 4.0.0.rc1 or greater.

You can see the `allow_nil` method was introduced in [this](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/commit/d49cfcae1b294e12a05e06a5612cb8ebb22a7df1) commit, which belongs to the 4.0.0 release.